# How to fix ASUS notebook freezing & brightness issues after Windows 10 Upgrade?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, freeze, brightness

My ASUS G73JH gaming notebook was working properly with the original Windows 7.  I upgraded it to Windows 10 and started experiencing a collection of problems:

- Inability to adjust screen brightness in the system configuration settings
- Keyboard backlight not working
- Random freezing, sometimes during startup and sometimes after login
- Sometimes get "MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION" Blue Screen of Windows 10

I tried reinstalling Windows 10 from scratch using an ISO on a USB drive, and running Windows Update, but these actions don't fix the problems.

*Note: This is a self-answered question intended to help others with some common problems of upgrading to Windows 10 on the ASUS notebook.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39801/discussion-on-question-by-abdulazizalmass-how-to-fix-asus-g73jh-freezing-brigh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This solution could work on other ASUS models, but it was only tested on G73JH.*

There are two keys to fixing this.

1. **Drivers**

   The correct drivers for the notebook are bundled in a package you need to get from ASUS.  Follow this upgrade sequence:

   - First, if the Windows 10 upgrade did not work using the automated process, install the ISO on an empty bootable USB drive.
   - After upgrading, let the laptop update everything from the Internet.
   - The Windows 7 drivers are not compatible with Windows 10, so do not reinstall any of the drivers from the original ATK package.
   - Install the latest [Asus Windows 10 ATK package](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/569/0/3/45/) for laptop drivers.
2. **Registry Patches**

   The final step is recommended if you experience screen brightness issues.

   > - Go to Registry Editor (regedit.exe)
   > - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000`
   > - Find:
   >
   >   `MD_EnableBrightnesslf2` 
   >      `KMD_EnableBrightnessInterface2`
   >
   >   Set both to `0`.
   > - Reboot.

---

*Credit for fixing the issues goes to [notebookreview forum](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/g73jh-windows-10-freezing.779600/)*

Comment: big thanks to  @fixer1234 for making q and a clear